# Save file names in database after uploaded, using plupload and mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, plupload

I am trying to save the name of each individual file in a database after they have been uploaded. I have this code that successfully uploads the files.

```
   $(function () {
    $("#uploader").plupload({
        // General settings
        runtimes: 'silverlight,flash,html5',
        url: '@Url.Content( "~/FileUploadChunks/UploadChunk" )',
        max_file_size: '10mb',
        chunk_size: '1mb',
        unique_names: true,
         // Flash settings
        flash_swf_url: '/plupload/js/plupload.flash.swf',
        // Silverlight settings
        silverlight_xap_url: '/plupload/js/plupload.silverlight.xap'
    });

});
```

This is the Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadChunk(int? chunk, int chunks, string name)
    {
        var fileUpload = Request.Files[0];
        var uploadpath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/UploadedFiles");
        chunk = chunk ?? 0;
        using (var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploadpath, name), chunk == 0 ? FileMode.Create : FileMode.Append))
        {
            var buffer = new byte[fileUpload.InputStream.Length];
            fileUpload.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
        return Content("chunk uploaded", "text/plain");
    }
```

Just to test, I tried something like this to try to capture the name and add them to a list to return to the view, but I cannot figure out how to print out the list in the view to see its contents.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadChunk(int? chunk, int chunks, string name)
    {
        var fileUpload = Request.Files[0];
        var uploadpath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/UploadedFiles");
        chunk = chunk ?? 0;
        using (var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploadpath, name), chunk == 0 ? FileMode.Create : FileMode.Append))
        {
            var buffer = new byte[fileUpload.InputStream.Length];
            fileUpload.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
        List<string> list = new List<string>();  

        foreach (string inputTagName in Request.Files)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file1 = Request.Files[inputTagName];
            if (file1.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                list.Add(file1.FileName);
            }
        }
        ViewBag.List = list;
       }
```

Ultimately I am just trying to loop through the names and save them in a database. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't give any information about you database, etc. for us to provide you with good help. However I'll give it a shot.

To answer your other question,

> I tried something like this to try to capture the name and add them to
>   a list to return to the view, but I cannot figure out how to print out
>   the list in the view to see its contents.

In your view, something like this should show them:

```
@foreach (string fileName in ViewBag.List)
{
    @fileName
    <br />
}
```

Assuming your using Entity Framework Code Fist, to save the file name to your database you need to have a model.

```
public class UploadedFileName
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

then in your controller you can alter the `foreach` statement you used to something like this:

```
foreach (HttpPostedFile file in Request.Files)
{        
    if (file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        UploadedFileName uploadedFile = new UploadedFileName();
        uploadedFile.Name = file.FileName;
        databaseContext.UploadedFileNames.Add(uploadedFile);
    }
}
```

The `HttpPostedFile` above may need to be `HttpPostedFileBase`, if you have an error. And the `databaseContext` is your database context, usually it is `db`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am still trying to get it to work. I am using link to SQL. The reason the @foreach wont work in the view is that is is initially empty and does not get contain anything so it throws an error. I need to somehow refresh it with the newly loaded data after submit. Thanks